# Asset management in yii2

Tags: yii

I have the code like this:

```
class BootBoxAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte';

    public $css = [
    ];

    public $js = [
        'https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.js'
    ];

    public $depends = [
        'plugins\jQuery\jquery-2.2.3.min.js',
        'bootstrap\js\bootstrap.min.js',
    ];

    public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
}
```

As the code shows above, I want to use bootbox.js which requires the related jquery and bootstrap dependency that located in my $sourcePath variable combined with the directories in $depends array,
when I register this asset in my view, there's an error tells me that the `Class plugins\jQuery\jquery-2.2.3.min.js does not exist`, so what should I do to register the dependency not start from `yii` directory?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this mean that you have wrong path for 
your dependency

```
  public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

then check for proper path

but for these assets you could use

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

Comment: Is there any ways that I can use my own dependency that not in the `yii` directory? For example, In the code above, I want to use the higher version of jquery as the dependency which locates in `@vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js` how can I make it?  @scaisEdge

Comment: yes  you can use your own dependency withoiut problem  .. but then you use  set  a valid path .. .. be sure for your files  position and path